# Replace internal antenna with external antenna

Tags: antenna, transmitter, receiver, pcb-antenna

I'm trying to figure out whether it's worth trying to replace an internal antenna for an external antenna of a uhf transmitter/receiver to get a stronger signal in order to get more distance from them and also less interference from walls etc.
I use them to make my microphones wireless.

These are the units in questions:
https://www.gear4music.com/PA-DJ-and-Lighting/Alto-Professional-Stealth-1-Mono-UHF-XLR-Wireless-System/53Z9?origin=product-ads&gclid=Cj0KCQjwgLOiBhC7ARIsAIeetVCY1APlVv-5eM_ZSzFHDVafcN2MgX7JWrvppVv9tRy7zgwUXA7DJnAaAkyUEALw_wcB

What problems could I encounter by trying this?

Edit: added picture of the board
[image: Rf board]
Thanks,
Sal

Comment: But the have a external antenna. The power on 863 - 865 MHz is limited  to 10mW. You can use a directional antenna, but then you have to follow the position of the transmitter with the receiver. A better solution is to bring the antenna more close to the transmitter, find a better place.

Comment: You should instead look for microphones which use lower frequencies and possibly more power, though I can't recommend any specific ones.

Comment: Attennas are already external only a little short. Just wind/attach a long wire around the antenna to extend the range. Easy peasy.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The microphones are usually used for speeches at weddings so it could be up to 30m away from the receiver but usually there aren't any walls in the way. I just wanted to see if it was easy enough to strengthen the signal. I'll try the wire trick.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the built-in whip antenna is permanently attached -- i.e., there's no standard connector. Given that, then I'd say it's not worth trying to replace the attached whip antenna with a different antenna on these units.

There are some things you can do to improve your link:

- Locate the receiving unit centrally so the distance from the transmitter(s) is as short as possible
- Orient the transmitting and receiving antennas both vertically, not horizontally or randomly

If that doesn't solve the issue, then upgrade your equipment. Better receivers, with dual antennas, provide diversity that reduces dropouts. If the receiver has antenna connector(s), you can swap in a directional antenna if it's located to one side of the stage where it can "see" all the transmitters.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It would've been interesting to see if i could solder in an SMA connector to the receiver unit and then attach a large external antenna but then i guess i'll have power issues considering these small units are only battery/usb operated?

Comment: A larger antenna would not consume more power. The challenge would be finding a suitable point for attaching the RF connector on the PCB with 50 ohm impedance and mechanical robustness. Disassemble and take photos of PCB to investigate.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Will do as soon as I can.

Comment: Pcb photo added

Comment: @Sal Thanks for photo; might be possible to add external antenna. First, buy a directional antenna for that frequency (example https://www.amazon.com/Tupavco-TP514-Directional-800MHz-960MHz-1-7-2-5GHz/dp/B008Z5QB96). Also get a cable that mates with it. At the opposite end, strip the jacket, free and "pigtail" the shield, and strip the center conductor. On the RECEIVER unit (not the transmitter=illegal) solder the center conductor where the old antenna was, and the shield to ground (the negative battery connector). Work out a strain relief for the cable. Might work!

Comment: Thanks Mark, this is perfect. Will give it a go!